# How I can include the use of the extension deck.automation.js when I create a document Rmarkdown-slidify-deck.js in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, slidify, deck.js

How I can include the use of the extension deck.automation.js when I create a document  Rmarkdown-slidify-deck.js in RStudio? It is to show a presentation on a screen with statistical content without interaction from anyone, and when finished will start automatically.

https://github.com/rchampourlier/deck.automatic.js

http://ramnathv.github.io/slidify/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [demo](http://slidify.github.io/add-deck-ext) of how to add this extension to `deckjs`, while using [Slidify](http://slidify.org). In short, here is what you need to do.

1. Use `author("mydeck")` to initialize deck, change `framework` to `deckjs` and run `slidify("index.Rmd")`
2. Download the extension `automatic` and add it to `libraries/frameworks/deckjs/extensions`.
3. Modify `libraries/frameworks/deckjs/config.yml` so that `automatic` is added to the list of extensions.
4. Modify `libraries/frameworks/deckjs/partials/snippet.html`, so that the javascript snippet required to initialize the extension is added.

You can also add an option for Play/Pause, as well as set custom slide durations. Instructions are in the [slide deck here](http://slidify.github.io/add-deck-ext).

UPDATE: The instructions here assume that you have the `dev` branches of Slidify and Slidifylibraries installed.

```
pkgs <- c("slidify", "slidifyLibraries")
devtools::install_github(pkgs, "ramnathv", ref = "dev")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. In the html code that is created appears 1.7 instead of 1.7.2:
  <!-- Grab CDN jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if offline -->
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="libraries/frameworks/deckjs/jquery-1.7.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

Comment: That should be alright, unless the features make use of the later versions of jQuery. I will update this in the next version of `slidifyLibraries`.